# Clear Cisco Stack-Ports "Changes to LinkOK" statistic

Tags: cisco

On Cisco switches with stacking cables, you can do:

```
#show switch stack-ports summary

Sw#/Port#  Port Status  Neighbor  Cable Length   Link OK   Link Active   Sync OK   #Changes to LinkOK  In Loopback
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1        OK           2         50cm           Yes       Yes           Yes       1                   No
1/2        OK           2         50cm           Yes       Yes           Yes       3                   No
2/1        OK           1         50cm           Yes       Yes           Yes       56                  No
2/2        OK           1         50cm           Yes       Yes           Yes       3                   No
```

How does one reset the count of "Changes to LinkOK"? For the life of me, I can't find the command!